# Replacing tub caulk

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, caulking

[image]

I have a question about replacing caulk. People always state that when you replace caulk, that you should remove all of it. My tub has caulking in red found in the image above. Do I really have to remove -all- of it or merely the parts that have mold (the parts at the bottom)

Comment: Newly caulked seal around the bath will have no joins and nowhere for the water to seep through. Putting new caulk on old caulk will leave you with a seam where water might be able to get through. You could remove the caulk around the bath and 6 inches up the sides above which it is unlikely water will get in (unless you have a shower in the tub). The ceiling caulk certainly can be kept since gravity will do its thing.

Comment: @scotty3785  This looks like an answer.

Comment: @jay613  This looks like an answer.

Comment: Fill the tub with water when re-caulking. It will lower the tub a little bit and compress the caulk when you let the water out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Remove all of it" means entirely remove every trace of old caulk from the areas that you are recaulking.  Don't put new caulk on top of old.   Establish smooth clean surfaces for the new caulk.

It does not mean that you have to keep expanding the scope of your project until you reach the end of the caulk line in every direction.
It is ok to leave caulk that's in good condition.  You just have to decide where to put the seams between old and new caulk lines, and don't create lots of them.

In the case of a bath tub in an alcove (like most are) I would redo the entire upper rim of the tub where it meets the wall, all three sides, in one continuous bead, and if necessary also a few inches up the walls where they meet in the corners.   After that I'd evaluate what's necessary.   You don't need to go all the way up the wall-corners or to do the ceiling-to-wall joints if they are in good shape.  It's ok to have a few joints between old and new caulk, just better not to do it where water pools.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a seam where water can get through where the new caulk meets the old caulk? or is it not really a huge deal if I move it up enough (the seam)
I have a shower

Comment: Yes, be reasonable in how you apply the idea of leaving old caulk that's in good shape.   Don't do a patchy job and don't leave seams where water pools.  Some obvious ones: You should do the whole tub/wall interface as one continuous new bead but you don't need to do the ceiling/wall interface at the same time.

Comment: Accepted answer. Could you elaborate on `Some obvious ones: You should do the whole tub/wall interface as one continuous new bead but you don't need to do the ceiling/wall interface at the same time`
I am not sure I understand? Thank you!

Comment: I added some elaboration in the answer.

Comment: Why does it have to be a continuous bead?  I thought that when you go over it with your finger tip, that makes it sufficiently continuous.  When I apply caulk, sometimes it's too thick and I have to push the excess along, and therefore I don't like to run an extremely long line continuously.  Does this mean that it's okay for me to caulk along a baseboard, for example, but I should stay away from the bathtub?

Comment: @aparente001 "continuous" means to not alternate removal of bad old caulk and leaving behind of good old caulk in a patchy fashion along the same caulk line in a critical area like a bath edge.  Redo the entire bead, as a continuous new one.  It does not mean that you have to get the entire new bead exactly right the first time directly from the tube.

Comment: @jay613 - Thanks -- whew.